# javascript trim or endswith TypeError:undefined is not a function (Cordova Android iOS)

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, cordova

A coworker on a different machine has added the following method to our Javascript application:

```
function setDomainUrl(url) {
  if (!url.trim().endsWith("/")) {
      url += "/";
      LoginVm.domainUrl = url;
  }
  globals.setKeyValue('DomainUrl', url);
  $window.localStorage.setItem("DomainUrl", url);
}
```

When I try running the application, it crashes after the first line of the method - "TypeError: undefined is not a function". I debugged to make sure that 'url' is a string, which it is ("http://www.google.com").

I am on an OS X machine. Could the crash be related to using different versions of Java? It is a pretty large Cordova app that has run fine up until this method was added. I should also note that I see the crash when I compile for Android, but not for iOS.

Comment: String.prototype.endsWith is part of ECMAScript 2015 which is not fully supported on all recent browsers

Comment: Android doesn't support it at all and iOS since v9: [Built-in extensions -> String.prototype methods -> String.prototype.endsWith](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-String.prototype_methods_String.prototype.endsWith)

Comment: @Andreas make it an answer and I'll accept